# How to address multi-dimensional lists in Python with random indexes

Tags: python

I'm looking for an efficient way to save in a multi-dimensional list different pointers to a file. 
My function triggers as soon as a job is sent to it. In each job, I get three values, `seq_id`, `cls_id` and `au_id`.
The first job initialise the `pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id]` as follows:

```
files = {}
pointers_list = []
pointers_list_flag = False

def worker(body):
    data = body['data']   
    file_id = body['file_id']
    seq_id = body['seq_id']
    cls_id = body['cls']
    au_id = body['au_id']

    if (file_id in files):
        pointers_list_flag = False
        files[file_id].append(body['du']) 
    else: 
        # first job
        files[file_id] = [body['du']]
        # do other stuffs only the first time
        [...]
        #init the pointers_list
        pointers_list.append([])
        pointers_list[seq_id].append([])
        pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id].append([])
        pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id] = 0
        pointers_list_flag = True
   if not pointers_list_flag:
       #the following jobs update the pointers_list
       current_pointer = getcurrentpointer()
       pointers_list.append([])
       pointers_list[seq_id].append([])
       pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id].append([])
       pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id] = current_pointer
```

Let's suppose my first job has `seq_id = 0`, `cls_id = 1` and `au_id = 0`. Obviously I get the error "index out of range" when I try to

```
    pointers_list[<seq_id=0>][<cls_id=1>].append([])
```

because I'm trying to access `pointers_list[0][1]`, while I've only init `pointers_list[0][0]`. The issue is that I can't know in advance neither the length and the values of any keys.
Any hints? shall I use dictionaries?

**EDIT 1:**

The dictionary `files` holds the jobs already processed. The list `pointers_list` instead holds the pointer (file.tell()) of the job with `seq_id, cls_id and au_id` to the output file. I need this because I receive the jobs with random order, but I need to write the output file with jobs data in a specified order, given indeed by `seq_id, cls_id and au_id`. Here the need for a list to hold the pointers. If I receive first the job with `seq_id=0, cls_id=1 and au_id=0`, I need my list to keep the pointer in the file where I started to write the data. When I receive a new job, let's say with `seq_id=0, cls_id=0 and au_id=0`, new data have to be written to the left of the current data in the output file. So, I've got to read pointers_list[0][1][0], get the point in the file where these data start, shift them by new data size and then write the new data. Finally, I need to update the pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id] of the data that has been shifted by new data.

I need the `pointers_list_flag` to prevent the first job to update again the `pointers_list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this purpose. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

`defaultdict` allows you to specify a `dict` like object but whenever a key is specified that is not already in the `defaultdict` a default value is created.

So for this example:

```
files = defaultdict(list)
pointers_list = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0)))

def worker(body):
    data = body['data']   
    file_id = body['file_id']
    seq_id = body['seq_id']
    cls_id = body['cls']
    au_id = body['au_id']

    if (file_id in files):
        current_pointer = getcurrentpointer()
        pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id] = current_pointer   
    else: 
        # do other things here
        [...]
        # Automatically creates entry in pointers list for seq_id -> cls_id -> au_id
        pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id] = 0     

    # If file_id in files then appends to list already there 
    # otherwise creates empty list for file_id entry and appends to the empty list    
    files[file_id].append(body['du'])
```

Note:

- A defaultdict argument must be a callable so thats why you have to use the `lambda:` functions
- The `pointers_list_flag` is actually redundant as the `file_id in files` statement handles everything

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In EDIT 1, I've explained better what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your edit and what you're trying to do. For the `pointers_list_flag` point, if you follow your original code through, you'll see that whatever the value of `pointers_list_flag` going in to the loop, the code in the first and third blocks are executed if `file_id in files` and the second if not

Comment: And as far as what you're trying to do with your lists and saving records, `defaultdict`   is the object for exactly this use case, it either creates a new entry when a new key is called, or sets the value for a key that is already in the dict. Which is what you're trying to do with your lists

Comment: The first job enters the else condition, initialises the file r/w pointer to zero and save the pointer value to pointers_list[seq_id][cls_id][au_id]. If I do not set the pointer_flag, the first job goes to the third block of code and resets the pointer_list value. I have stuffs to do in the third block that the first job does not have to execute.

Comment: getcurrentpointer() not yet implemented but it will return the current r/w pointer (file.tell()).
I will implement the defaultdict list as you suggested and come back. 
Thank you

Comment: Have another look at the code and maybe draw a diagram to understand why the flag is obsolete. The first line of code asks if `file_id in files`. This is always executed. If `True` then the first block is executed and `pointers_list_flag` is set to `False`. If `False` then the second block is executed and `pointers_list_flag` is set to `True`. The third block is executed if and only if `pointers_list_flag == False`. But then `pointers_list_flag` is `False` if and only if the first block is executed which happens if and only if `file_id in files`. So the flag is actually redundant.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I was not clear. My comment about the need for a flag to skip the third block if current job is the first one was referred to the code without the pointer_flag, the code you wrote for example.

Comment: Have you drawn a flow chart? That might help to see how the flag isn't useful in either my code or your code. Try it and hopefully it'll become a bit clearer.

Comment: I do understand what is going on with the pointer flag. Maybe I was not clear on what I'm trying to accomplish. @hilton92 wrote "The first line of code asks if file_id in files. This is always executed. If True then the first block is executed and pointers_list_flag is set to False. If False then the second block is executed and pointers_list_flag is set to True.". The second block is executed only once, the first time ever the worker() is called. In this case (the first time), I want the code to enter the second block but to skip the third one.

Comment: The 3rd block is skipped if and only if pointers_list_flag is True, so ONLY in the case of the first job, when I set pointers_list_flag to True. That's what I need in this piece of code.

Comment: One of the principles of programming is to keep your code as simple as possible and remove unnecessary variables. (https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/why-unnecessary-variables-are-bad-your-code) - So in your case, can you remove this variable and still have the exact same functionality? Yes. Even without the defaultdict optimisation and just rewriting your original code then this has the exact same functionality as your original code and removes the flag variable.
See here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kboZbgotsjbeVFFq4pjE5nPis8u3O4P5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Theres a seperate issue as to whether you want the second block to execute only on the first call of the worker ever, or if you want it to execute if the `file_id` is not in files. You currently have the second situation set up. You would need to do something different if you want the first and there a flag may be more useful, but then you would not have the `file_id in files` check

Comment: Did you have a bug in your original code here? Removing `pointers_list_flag = False` in the first block would give you the behaviour you were expecting where the third block runs once. Its not clear if you want the third block to run if theres a new file or just once.

Either way `defaultdict` basically handles this all for you and you dont need to bother with either check